# Validation with Ajax and MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, validation

I am looking at the best way to take advantage of the MVC validation while using Ajax and not having access to a class.

On my masterpage it will contain a simple form (name, email, tel, comments) which I display in a overlay. As this is in the masterpage is available on any page, The masterpage never inherits a class like you would do when normally validating. So im not sure how (or if its still possible) to validate my form in the same way.

I thought creating a class with the same validation rules i would normally apply would help and then trying to maybe load this from viewdata? is this the best way to go or will validation not work doing this?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2 has built-in support for client-side validation, using the server-side rules. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Comment: yeh thats what im currently using on other "normal" pages. but how can I get it to pick up the correct Class when my page doesn't inherit from a class? Like in the example Scott guthrie shows he has a class called person. how would his client side validation pick that up without his page inherting the class person?

Comment: I see what you mean. Isn't there a `ValidationFor()` that could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side validation will still work if you create a server side class with validation rules. But adding client input fields will have to be done manually and not using the view model:

```
<% using Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller") %>
<% { %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Name") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Email") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Phone") %>
    <%= Html.TextArea("CommentText") %>
<% } %>
```

Your controller action would look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(Comment comment)
{
    if (!this.Model.IsValid)
    {
        // handle model state exception
    }
    // save comment
    return // whatever needed
}
```

of course as long as you have a class:

```
public class Comment
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(/* provide the email reg ex here */)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required] // probably, but you'd know best
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
}
```

And while doing it I urge you to read [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/handling-validation-errors-on-ajax.html) about Asp.net MVC ajax and model validation, that may help you lots.